# How to solve blur and submit event simultaneous in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have text box in my page, which i can enter 9 digit number. **Onblur** I am validating like the entered number is valid or not using **API** call, If service returns failure it will clear the text box with red border and form will be invalid. The event conflict happening between **OnBlur** and **Submit**. **Submit** service will call only the form is valid otherwise it will show toaster like enter mandatory filed.

If the text field focused and directly if I click on submit button, both event calling simultaneously and it is clearing the number field **OnBlur** as well as the service is calling.

Please can you help me to resolve this conflicts.

**file.html**

```
<form class="contact-form" #create="ngForm">
    <div class="controls">
      <input NumberOnly="true" type="text" id="num" [ngClass]="{'red-border-class': ((showErrorFlag == true && numberField.errors) || (showErrorFlag == true && numberField.errors && (numberField.dirty || numberField.touched)))}"
  [disabled]="disableRotaDetailFields" [(ngModel)]="number"
   class="floatLabel" name="ownership" required #numberField="ngModel" (blur)="validatenumber(number)" [maxLength]="einLength">
<label for="ein">number<sup>*</sup></label>
</div>
<button (click)="SaveData(create)">Save</button>
</form>
```

**file.ts**

```
public validatenumber(number) {
        let reqObj = {
          "ownership": number
        }

        this.calloutService.validateOwnerEin(reqObj)
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
          .subscribe((data) => {
          }, (err) => {
            if (err.status == 404) {
              this.number = "";
            }
            this.toastr.error(err.overriddenMessage);
          })

      }

    SaveData(){
    if (!formFlag.valid ) {
        this.showErrorFlag = true;
        this.toastr.error('Please fill all the mandatory fields');
    }else {
      this.calloutService.createData(this.data)
          .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
          .subscribe(data => {
            this.showSpinnerFlag = false;
            let response = data;
            if (data) {
              this.toastr.success("Rota created successfully.");
            } else {
              this.toastr.error("Could not save.");
            }
          }, err => {
            this.showSpinnerFlag = false;
            this.toastr.error(err.overriddenMessage);
          })
    }
}
```

Comment: so onsubmit check if the call is still active, it it is wait until it is not active.

Comment: It doesn't solve your issue, but it's against good practices to clean the input if the entered value is deemed invalid. Ideally the user would like to see what was wrong and amend it themselves.

Comment: @melancia- It will clean the field when ```validatenumber()``` service returns false and showing alert to user, but still its calls create service.

Comment: What I suggested was to not clean the input. But like I said, that's unrelated to your question and won't solve the reported issue.